# Suggested reading order for The Saga of Recluce

Tags: suggested-order, l-e-modesitt

Is there any order for reading *The Saga of Recluce* by L. E. Modesitt? I want to start reading it, but I don’t know where to begin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Read them in publication order.**

Quoting from the [Wikipedia page for *Saga of Recluce*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saga_of_Recluce):

> [The books] are listed in order of publication: the author has stated that this is the appropriate reading order.

That means you should start with *The Magic of Recluce*.

You can find the [full list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saga_of_Recluce#Books); I won’t copy it here as it will quickly become out-of-date, and such a list should be easy to find even if Wikipedia goes away.